# NoFileSpecified error when trying to upload a file to OneDrive

Tags: android, onedrive

I'm using Android and I am following this tutorial:

https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-picker-android/blob/master/README.md

```
public void uploadToOneDrive(String content,Context context){
    final String filename = "Temp.xml";
    final File f = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("Temp.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));

        outputStreamWriter.write(content);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }

    System.out.println("File " + f.toString());
    mSaver = Saver.createSaver(ONEDRIVE_APP_ID);
    mSaver.startSaving((Activity)context,filename, Uri.fromFile(f));

}
```

This is my method that returns ERROR TYPE NoFileSpecified. I am trying to just create a new temporary file, put a string into it and then delete it.

This is how I call it:

```
        oneDriveUpload.getSaver().handleSave(requestCode, resultCode, data);

05-29 15:03:18.649 10649-10649/david.projectclouds I/System.out: File /data/user/0/david.projectclouds/files/Temp.xml
05-29 15:03:18.702 10649-10649/david.projectclouds I/System.out: URI:  file:///data/user/0/david.projectclouds/files/Temp.xml
```

So there is a file and the URI is something that is accepted. I'm lost.

EDIT: I've tried using content content://david.projectclouds.MainActivity/file/diabetix/Temp.xml

But I still have the same error.

Comment: You are not using File f for your output stream writer. That is not a good idea. Adapt your code to use it, Now you create a file of which you hope it will be the same as f.

Comment: `This is my method that returns ERROR TYPE NoFileSpecified. I ` It is unclear which code line is producing that error.

Comment: Of course you should alse use f.exists() to check if the file exists before you try to upload it.

Comment: @greenapps would this work             OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput(String.valueOf(f), Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
This is in activityForResult
            oneDriveUpload.getSaver().handleSave(requestCode, resultCode, data);

When I use              System.out.println("ERROR TYPE "+ e.getErrorType()); it prints it out.

Comment: Do not use openFileOutput. Use FileOutputStream. Please put code in your post. Not in a comment. Its unreadable in comments.

Comment: Hey sorry for being this late. I was working full time and couldnt really get around to working on my project. I've since started to use fos. http://i.imgur.com/QJxMUPV.png 

This is what my code looks like. f.exists() outputs true. If you have any more questions dont hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are apparently some issues with Android 7.0 and the SDK. So I just used my own intents.

```
 Intent intentOD = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                intentOD.setType("text/*");
                                intentOD.setPackage("com.microsoft.skydrive");

                                intentOD.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                                intentOD.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "david.projectclouds.MainActivity", f));
                                getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentOD, "title"));
```